# linux assembly: how to call syscall?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I want to call a syscall in assembly. The problem is I can't `mov ecx,rsp`. `rsp` is 64-bit register, `ecx` is a 32-bit register. I want to pass the buffer addr as a parameter of this syscall. What can I do? Thanks.

```
section .data 
s0: db "Largest basic function number supported:%s\n",0
s0len: equ $-s0

section .text 
global main
extern write
main: 
sub rsp, 16
xor eax, eax
cpuid

mov [rsp], ebx
mov [rsp+4], edx
mov [rsp+8], ecx 
mov [rsp+12], word 0x0

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, rsp
mov edx, 4 
int 80h

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, s0
mov edx, s0len 
int 80h

mov eax, 1
int 80h
```

Comment: If you're writing a 64-bit app, should you be using the [64-bit way of doing syscalls](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) ?

Comment: What's with the weird mix of bitness? I sense an attempt to merge a 32-bit sample into a 64-bit project...

Answer (score 20):

To make a system call in 64-bit Linux, place the system call number in rax, and its arguments, in order, in rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, and r9, then invoke syscall.

Note that 64-bit call numbers are different from 32-bit call numbers.

Here is an example in GAS syntax.  NASM syntax for putting an address in a register is `lea rsi, [rel message]` using a RIP-relative LEA.

```
        .global _start

        .text
_start:
        # write(1, message, 13)
        mov     $1, %rax                # system call 1 is write
        mov     $1, %rdi                # file handle 1 is stdout
        lea     message(%rip), %rsi     # address of string to output
        mov     $13, %rdx               # number of bytes
        syscall

        # exit(0)
        mov     $60, %rax               # system call 60 is exit
        xor     %rdi, %rdi              # return code 0
        syscall

.section .rodata           # read-only data section
message:
        .ascii  "Hello, World\n"
```

---

See also [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)